# lightbox idtabs conflict

Tags: css, navigation

I have two javascripts that I think are in a conflict. idTabs, which helps me make the navigation and lightbox, which is the photo gallery. I also want to add that I have a 3rd page linked, a PHP `SELECT` from database page.

this is in my head

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox0/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox0/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>


>      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox0/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
    </script>
```

I dont understand what the light box doesn work. the id tabs works perfectly but when i click on a page, it doesn have the lightbox effect. i tried with at least 4-5 lightobx versions, the same effect. help ?

Comment: Does the console show any JavaScript errors? Or do you have the page online anywhere we can see?

Comment: i dont know where to look for errors . it s local.the page works fine, the idtab script works fine,lets me surf through the pages of the navigation, but the lightbox effect is gone..

Comment: You seem to have an erroneous `>` on your `<link rel` line. Probably not the reason for your problems, but you should remove it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

idTabs should be loaded after jQuery. Try the following:

```
<script src="lightbox0/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lightbox0/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
```

*Sanity Check*: Do you have a `<div id="gallery">` with links in it in the page?